# Edittext with input type password does not show correct font on Nexus devices

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have used `EditText` with input type text for username field and input type password for password field.
The fonts used for both `EditText` is same.
But for nexus devices the font for hint text appears different for password field.
This issue is not observed on other devices.
Could anybody please provide a solution for this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: put your xml file please :)

Comment: post your xml layout code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following line on your `EditText` with password.

```
myEditTextPassword.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
myEditTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

**OR**

Remove `android:inputType="textPassword"` from XML and add following line in code:

```
myEditTextPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```